# Split Screen styling

Tags: android, user-interface

I am developing an app that has a similar screen layout to the GMail screenshot shown here

http://newbestgadget.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/GoTab-GTi8.jpg

My question is how to achieve the styling on the rows of the left hand side listview(?).
I assume this is achieved by the use of background images? Is this the best way to achieve this?

What would the background image look like for the item that is selected?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's a Background image trick. The right hand side has a white nine-patch with a little drop-shadow. The small triangular portion you see on in extreme right of the selected list item is also a nine-patch image matching that of the right hand side area. This is background of a dummy view (right aligned, on top of rest of item layout) that is visible only for selected item. This way when you scroll the list the triangle also moves with it.

Detailed answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14032449/1531054

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of [`Fragments`](http://marakana.com/s/post/1250/android_fragments_tutorial). Its the new way of designing interactive screens.

Comment: Waqas - thanks for the link, Got to agree Fragments are very useful, but not sure how this helps with respect to styling.

Comment: i don't see any special styling which requires you to make use of a background image. Simply toggle the background color between read and unread messages. dont you think so?

Comment: Also need to cater for the triangle on the selected item.