# Master detail split styling in android

Tags: android, styling, master-detail

*This question probably has been asked many times over here, without yielding useful answers. I'd place it here with a possible answer. Feel free to improve.*

**Question:** How to setup popup like style of detail view, in side by side master detail view as highlighted in image below:

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In this solution , I have used 9-patch background images, to define 2 kinds of backgrounds for list items. So, the selected(checked) list Item has a different background, as shown:

[image] (list item)

[image] (selected item)

[image] (list item)

The list item layout's parent view, is a class extending `LinearLayout` (can be any `ViewGroup`) and implementing `Checkable`. Hence, when `ListView` is set to choice mode, it can automatically check/uncheck this view. This checked state is then used by `selector` background assigned to this view :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked"/>
</selector>
```

This makes the background of list item view change automatically, without having to do it manually in code every time a list item is selected.

**Result:**

[image]

**Additional points:**

1. Scrollbar can be moved to left side.
2. Use list dividers that match shadow color, or more padding can be placed between list items and detail view.