# Create Fragment layout like this?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to create the layout for my fragment like this example . that in the left i have list view and in the right i have detail of that . now what i want to do is that create layout like this example that from detail point to selected row of the list view in the left . is there any one to help me ?[image]

Comment: you have to create a png with that shape. Then you can try set it as foreground for a FrameLayout with a Transparent background

Comment: but how point to the selected row . my problem is pointing to the selected row . as in image i draw a red rectangle .

Comment: Imo nothing is pointed. The huge layout on the right is withe and squared. Is the cell that chages drawable when its state changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer here : 
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032448/master-detail-split-styling-in-android)

I should use 2 9-patch image Like :

[image: item]  ListItem

[image: selected item] ListSelectedItem

and after that I can use selector or I can do this  :

in my OnItemSelected method I use :

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        SelectedItem =position;
}

and in my adapter :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = convertView;

            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_list_row, null);
            }

if (position ==SelectedItem )
{
   v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ListSelectedItem );
}
else
{ 
   v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ListItem);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: IMG]

Assume we use two fragments to implement this page. Fragment A is a list fragment which represent the peoples name, and Fragment B is the content fragment which show the details of selected user.

When you click a item in Fragment A, B is added in the blue view container, blue container is draw after the black one, so Fragment B will overlap Fragment A. The white pointer you want is just a png background of Fragment B.

Comment: i know that it's a png in B background but i dont know how to make te little triangle to point to the selected item in A fragment list view

Comment: @pooyan You can get the position of the selectedItem in your listView, and pass the position to Fragment B

Comment: yes i can but it is not enough . it just get me the position of selected item in listview , but i need it coordinate !! i hope you understand what i mean !

Comment: @pooyan use ListView.getSelectedView() to get the selected view, and use View.getTop() to get the top position in its parent. Use the coordinates of Fragment A, B and the selected view to calculate the coordinates of the pointer, not very hard.

Comment: thanks's for your help . i think i understand what i should do !